# Suggest a good image upload-and-crop tool

Tags: php, jquery, upload, crop, jcrop

I'd like to know which up-and-crop tools you suggest to me. I tried couple of scripts like JCrop but I always get stack with some type of format like bmp. I either can't upload or I can upload but can't crop. If you use (or know) one that works well with different formats, then please just give me its name and I'll be strongly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Well, i dont know much about JCrop but you can build it up with several tools. 
I think image processing kind of works should be done on server side.
There is a good OOP Library called [Imagine](https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine). It's mostly based on Python's Imaging Library which is awesome and has decent documentation. And [this](http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/Filter/Basic/Crop.html#Imagine%5CFilter%5CBasic%5CCrop%3a%3aapply) is its crop functions documentation.

On client side you can use some kind of image area selection tool to let the user determine desired area to crop. [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) is good to go. Then you can send crop area to php by [JQuery's post function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or any other way.

Comment: Ok thanks. I think the best way is to build and personalize it by myself. Thanks dear for the tools.

Answer (score 0):

It's amassing that in all this time this haven't got any other answers, I hope this helps.

Like stated in the other answer you should combine a few tools to solve each part of the problem.

1. To let the user **select** the cropping area:

   If you don't like jCrop you can try [Guillotine](//matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine). It's very lightweight, easy to set up and allows to crop, zoom and rotate images. It has touch support and it's responsive (fluid).

   Keep in mind that you can't display image types that the browser doesn't support, but you can convert them in step 3.
2. To **upload** the images:

   For most cases, once you have the cropping area, with a simple file input will suffice.

   Now, if you want to upload files **asynchronously** check out 
   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809587/asynchronous-jquery-file-upload/25100016#25100016) 
   for a quick and easy set up or [this](//github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) 
   for a more complex solution.
3. To actually **crop** and process the image:

   Once uploaded you can crop, convert and process the images on the server, [ImageMagick](//imagemagick.org) is a great tool for this. It's Open Source and many languages have wrappers for it.

   You've tagged the question with *PHP* so here is a [PHP wrapper for ImageMagick](//php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php).