# Asynchronous JQUERY File Upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload

I have HTML form with a file input type. I need to submit the form asynchronously to the server. The server listens for a incoming file upload (multi part file upload) request. Is it possible to achieve this using jquery.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use jQuery's `$.ajax()` method to send files if [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) and the [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) are supported (both HTML5 features).

You can also send files [without FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Submitting_forms_and_uploading_files) but either way the File API must be present to process files in such a way that they can be sent with XMLHttpRequest (Ajax).

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file/destination.html', 
  type: 'POST',
  data: new FormData($('#formWithFiles')[0]),  // The form with the file inputs.
  processData: false  // Using FormData, don't process data.
}).done(function(){
  console.log("Success: Files sent!");
}).fail(function(){
  console.log("An error occurred, the files couldn't be sent!");
});
```

For a quick, pure JavaScript example see "[Sending files using a FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects#Sending_files_using_a_FormData_object)".

If you want to add a **fallback** for older browsers or if you want just one **cross-browser** implementation use the [Bifröst](//github.com/matiasgagliano/bifrost). It adds an extra [jQuery Ajax transport](//api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport) allowing to send **files** with plane old `$.ajax()`.

Simply add *jquery.bifrost.js* and make the request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'file/destination.html', 
  type: 'POST',
  // Set the transport to use (iframe means to use Bifröst)
  // and the expected data type (json in this case).
  dataType: 'iframe json',                                
  fileInputs: $('input[type="file"]'),  // The file inputs containing the files to send.
  data: { msg: 'Some extra data you might need.'}
}).done(function(){
  console.log("Success: Files sent!");
}).fail(function(){
  console.log("An error occurred, the files couldn't be sent!");
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to achieve this using jquery.

No, not directly with jQuery.

You could use the HTML5 File API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Or if you need to support legacy browsers you could use some plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/), [`Fine Uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/) or the [`jQuery form plugin`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this jQuery plugin:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload