# Image upload on file chosen not on submit form ,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a HTML form where the user can upload an image in the input field and it works fine but the image is uploaded when the form is submitted.

Is there a way where I can get the image to upload to the TMP directory when the file is chosen and the user is still filling out the form then when the user submits the form it can be moved to the actual file directory. This would make for a better user experience and especially people with slow internet connections would benefit from this as it would utilise the users time for effectively and efficiently.

I am not sure exactly but I think this would need some sort of jQuery/Ajax solution to upload the image mid form entry then use PHP to transfer the file from the TMP to the actual directory.

Comment: Use two forms. Submit the image form to a hidden iframe.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  This site is really about code.

Comment: Try change event of file type input

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous JQUERY File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809587/asynchronous-jquery-file-upload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Diodeus suggested, putting the form in an iframe would prevent it from posting in the current page frame and allow users to work on other form items. A solution more to what you were expecting would be using an AJAX request. You could look into the HTML5 API, there are many different already-built solutions and many tutorials.

Here's a simple example taken from [this demo at html5demos.com](http://html5demos.com/file-api)

```
<title>Drag and drop, automatic upload</title>
<style>
#holder { border: 10px dashed #ccc; width: 300px; min-height: 300px; margin: 20px auto;}
#holder.hover { border: 10px dashed #0c0; }
#holder img { display: block; margin: 10px auto; }
#holder p { margin: 10px; font-size: 14px; }
progress { width: 100%; }
progress:after { content: '%'; }
.fail { background: #c00; padding: 2px; color: #fff; }
.hidden { display: none !important;}
</style>
<article>
    <div id="holder">
    </div> 
    <p id="upload" class="hidden"><label>Drag &amp; drop not supported, but you can still upload via this input field:<br><input type="file"></label></p>
    <p id="filereader">File API &amp; FileReader API not supported</p>
    <p id="formdata">XHR2's FormData is not supported</p>
    <p id="progress">XHR2's upload progress isn't supported</p>
    <p>Upload progress: <progress id="uploadprogress" min="0" max="100" value="0">0</progress></p>
    <p>Drag an image from your desktop on to the drop zone above to see the browser both render the preview, but also upload automatically to this server.</p>
</article>
<script>
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
        tests = {
            filereader: typeof FileReader != 'undefined',
            dnd: 'draggable' in document.createElement('span'),
            formdata: !!window.FormData,
            progress: "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest
        }, 
        support = {
            filereader: document.getElementById('filereader'),
            formdata: document.getElementById('formdata'),
            progress: document.getElementById('progress')
        },
        acceptedTypes = {
            'image/png': true,
            'image/jpeg': true,
            'image/gif': true
        },
        progress = document.getElementById('uploadprogress'),
        fileupload = document.getElementById('upload');

"filereader formdata progress".split(' ').forEach(function (api) {
    if (tests[api] === false) {
        support[api].className = 'fail';
    } else {
        // FFS. I could have done el.hidden = true, but IE doesn't support
        // hidden, so I tried to create a polyfill that would extend the
        // Element.prototype, but then IE10 doesn't even give me access
        // to the Element object. Brilliant.
        support[api].className = 'hidden';
    }
});

function previewfile(file) {
    if (tests.filereader === true && acceptedTypes[file.type] === true) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (event) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.src = event.target.result;
            image.width = 250; // a fake resize
            holder.appendChild(image);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }    else {
        holder.innerHTML += '<p>Uploaded ' + file.name + ' ' + (file.size ? (file.size/1024|0) + 'K' : '');
        console.log(file);
    }
}

function readfiles(files) {
        debugger;
        var formData = tests.formdata ? new FormData() : null;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (tests.formdata) formData.append('file', files[i]);
            previewfile(files[i]);
        }

        // now post a new XHR request
        if (tests.formdata) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open('POST', '/devnull.php');
            xhr.onload = function() {
                progress.value = progress.innerHTML = 100;
            };

            if (tests.progress) {
                xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
                    if (event.lengthComputable) {
                        var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
                        progress.value = progress.innerHTML = complete;
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.send(formData);
        }
}

if (tests.dnd) { 
    holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
    holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
    holder.ondrop = function (e) {
        this.className = '';
        e.preventDefault();
        readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
    }
} else {
    fileupload.className = 'hidden';
    fileupload.querySelector('input').onchange = function () {
        readfiles(this.files);
    };
}

</script>
```

This creates a zone to drop a file (instead of a browse button) and initiate the file upload when the drag and drop event occurs. It will do it asynchronously and allow the page contents to be interacted with as normal while the transfer proceeds in the background. There is an important thing in this example to change, however. This line:

```
xhr.open('POST', '/devnull.php');
```

Should be changed to a code file in your environment/server that will process the file upload data and save or process the file however you need. This script merely acts as a front-end to that script. Another thing to remember is the [HTML5 File API is still a modern-browser-only type of thing; it's well supported in current browsers, but older ones are out of luck](http://caniuse.com/fileapi). If you need to have them supported, you should look for another solution.